# Performance issue when I have to set attribute of a model in multiple places (model bind to a change event)

Tags: backbone.js, bind, onchange, silent

I am binding my modal to the change event

```
@model.bind('change', @someAction)
```

Will performance of my app be affected if I am required to set/change attribute of my model and multiple places i.e. @model.set({someAttr:'attributeA'})?

Does doing a {silent: true}, @model.set({someAttr:'attributeA'}, {silent: true}) solve the problem of performance of the app?

Comment: Well, if `@someAction` is required to be executed after updating the `attribute`, for example if it renders the view and view should have the latest value of attribute, then you need to execute it. Else `{silent: true}` will prevent `change trigger` and `model validation` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends". It's up to you to figure out what changes to your model deserve change events and which do not. There is no magical answer in this case to improve performance.

Passing `{silent:true}` is one way to prevent the change event from firing. Another optimization is to listen to changes to specific attributes within your model.

```
@model.bind('change:myAttr', @someAction)
```

This way, your action is triggered only if a specific attribute is changed and does not trigger if any other attributes are changed.